# ¿como solucionar error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'value' y capturar.html:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: CapturarAlumnos is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

Cuando quiero correr mi codigo me sale esto: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'value', y cuando quiero capturar los datos ingresados, me sale esto: capturar.html:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: CapturarAlumnos is not defined

Y ese error me sale con todas los botones que tengo, al presionarlos

alguien me ayuda??
No sé cual es el error

```
<html>

<body>
  <center>
    <button type="button" onclick="CapturarAlumnos();">Capturar Alumnos</button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="CapturarDocentes();">Capturar Docentes</button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MostrarAlumnos();">Mostrar Alumnos</button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MostrarDocentes();">Mostrar Docentes</button><br><br>
    <label>Nombre:</label><input id="Nom"><br><br>
    <label>Edad:</label><input id="Ed"><br><br>
    <label>Carrera:</label><input id="Carr"><br><br>
    <h2>Personas Capturadas:</h2>
    <ul id="listaPersonas"></ul>

    <script>

      class Persona {
        constructor(nombre, edad, carrera) {
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.edad = edad;
          this.carrera = carrera;
        }
        saludar() {
          return "Esta persona es " + $(this.nombre) + " tiene " + $(this.edad) + " de la carrera " + $(this.carrera);
        }
      }

      let personas1 = [];
      let personas2 = [];

      function CapturarAlumnos() {
        const nombre1 = document.getElementById("Nom").value;
        const edad1 = document.getElementById("Ed").value;
        const carrera1 = document.getElementById("Carr").value;
        const nuevaPersona1 = new Persona(nombre1, edad1, carrera1)
        personas1.push(nuevaPersona1)
      }
      function CapturarDocentes() {
        const nombre2 = document.getElementById("Nom").value;
        const edad2 = document.getElementById("Ed").value;
        const carrera2 = document.getElementById("Carr").value;
        const nuevaPersona2 = new Persona(nombre2, edad2, carrera2)
        personas2.push(nuevaPersona2)
      }
      function MostrarAlumnos() {
        document.getElementById("listaPersonas").innerHTML = + personas1.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < personas1.lenght; i++) {
          const listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = personas1[i].saludar();
          listaPersonas.appendChild(listItem);
        }
      }
      function MostrarDocentes() {
        document.getElementById("listaPersonas").innerHTML = personas2.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < personas2.lenght; i++) {
          const listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = personas2[i].saludar();
          listaPersonas.appendChild(listItem);
        }
      }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

este es el codigo completo:

```
<html>
<body>
    <center>
    <button type="button" onclick="CapturarAlumnos();">Capturar Alumnos</button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="CapturarDocentes();">Capturar Docentes</button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MostrarAlumnos();">Mostrar Alumnos</button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MostrarDocentes();">Mostrar Docentes</button><br><br>
    <label>Nombre:</label><input id="Nom"><br><br>
    <label>Edad:</label><input id="Ed"><br><br>
    <label>Carrera:</label><input id="Carr"><br><br>
    <h2>Personas Capturadas:</h2><ul id= "listaPersonas"></ul>

<script>

class Persona
{
    constructor(nombre, edad, carrera)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.carrera = carrera;
    }
    saludar(){
    return "Esta persona es " + $(this.nombre) + " tiene " + $(this.edad) + " de la carrera "+ $(this.carrera);
    }
}

let personas1 = [];
let personas2 = [];

function CapturarAlumnos(){
    const nombre1 = document.getElementById("Nom").value;
    const edad1 = document.getElementById("Ed").value;
    const carrera1 = document.getElementById("Carr").value;
    const nuevaPersona1 = new Persona(nombre1, edad1, carrera1)
    personas1.push(nuevaPersona1)
}
function CapturarDocentes(){
    const nombre2 = document.getElementById("Nom").value;
    const edad2 = document.getElementById("Ed").value;
    const carrera2 = document.getElementById("Carr").value;
    const nuevaPersona2 = new Persona(nombre2, edad2, carrera2)
    personas2.push(nuevaPersona2)
}
function MostrarAlumnos(){
    document.getElementById("listaPersonas").innerHTML= + personas1.length_+;   
    for (let i = 0; i < personas1.lenght; i++)
     {
        const listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.textContent = personas1[i].saludar();
        listaPersonas.appendChild(listItem);
    }
}
function MostrarDocentes(){
    document.getElementById("listaPersonas").innerHTML=personas2.length;    
    for (let i = 0; i < personas2.lenght; i++)
     {
        const listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.textContent = personas2[i].saludar();
        listaPersonas.appendChild(listItem);
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: en mostrar alumno dice length_+

Comment: @Bryro de hecho dice 'lenght' XD

Comment: @andy pon el código completo, a mi no me aparece ese error aunque hay otros errores, al parecer no tienes el JS en un archivo separado sino dentro del HTML, pon el HTML completo

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ ya lo puse en los comentarios, bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios errores:

- Cierra la etiqueta `<center>` con su tag de cierre `</center>` (este elemento esta obsoleto y no se recomienda su uso, solo se mantiene por temas de retrocompatibilidad, mejor usa CSS).
- En el método *saludar* al devolver la cadena concatenas de una forma extraña, no se si estas usando JQuery, pero de todas formas devuelve [Object object]. Usa una concatenación clásica o [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- Hay errores de ortografía, longitud es 'length' no 'lenght'
- En *mostrarAlumnos* tienes esto: personas1.length_+, ese guion y ese símbolo de + no van (tu IDE no te lo advierte? si no lo hace considera usar otro)

En cualquier caso, aquí esta la corrección:

```html
    <html lang="es">
    <body>
      <center>
        <button type="button" onclick="CapturarAlumnos();">Capturar Alumnos</button><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="CapturarDocentes();">Capturar Docentes</button><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="MostrarAlumnos();">Mostrar Alumnos</button><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="MostrarDocentes();">Mostrar Docentes</button><br><br>
        <label>Nombre:</label><input id="Nom"><br><br>
        <label>Edad:</label><input id="Ed"><br><br>
        <label>Carrera:</label><input id="Carr"><br><br>
        <h2>Personas Capturadas:</h2>
        <ul id="listaPersonas"></ul>
      </center>
    
      <script>
        class Persona {
          constructor(nombre, edad, carrera) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.carrera = carrera;
          }
          saludar() {
            return "Esta persona es " + this.nombre + " tiene " + this.edad + " de la carrera " + this.carrera;
          }
        }
    
        let personas1 = [];
        let personas2 = [];
    
        function CapturarAlumnos() {
          const nombre1 = document.getElementById("Nom").value;
          const edad1 = document.getElementById("Ed").value;
          const carrera1 = document.getElementById("Carr").value;
          const nuevaPersona1 = new Persona(nombre1, edad1, carrera1)
          personas1.push(nuevaPersona1)
        }
        function CapturarDocentes() {
          const nombre2 = document.getElementById("Nom").value;
          const edad2 = document.getElementById("Ed").value;
          const carrera2 = document.getElementById("Carr").value;
          const nuevaPersona2 = new Persona(nombre2, edad2, carrera2)
          personas2.push(nuevaPersona2)
        }
        function MostrarAlumnos() {
          document.getElementById("listaPersonas").innerHTML = + personas1.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < personas1.length; i++) {
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.textContent = personas1[i].saludar();
            listaPersonas.appendChild(listItem);
          }
        }
        function MostrarDocentes() {
          document.getElementById("listaPersonas").innerHTML = personas2.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < personas2.length; i++) {
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.textContent = personas2[i].saludar();
            listaPersonas.appendChild(listItem);
          }
        }
    
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```